# how to force Show() to execute now, not after others methods

Tags: c#, winforms

In the baseform of a winform project the code for connecting to the database is moved from the load event to the show event.
In the show event there is a call to Update() before fetching data, this makes the form appear much faster which is more pleasant for the users.

But now I found code on some places like this for example :

```
FormRitDetail ritDetail = new FormRitDetail();
ritDetail.PrimaryKeyValue = ritID;
ritDetail.Show();
ritDetail.SendSaleEmail(cancelSale);
ritDetail.Close();
```

This worked perfect while the code for fetching data was in the load event, but now it gives an error which I have tracked down. In the SendSaleEmail method the data is not fetched yet.

The fetching happens in the Shown() event, but it seems that c# does the call to SendSaleEmail first, and than the call to Show().

How can I force c# to do the methods in the order as I write them ?
I can do a call to ritDetail.Update() after the ritDetail.Show() I know that, but I would like a general solution that does not involves writing additional code everywhere the show() method is called.

Is this possible ?

Comment: is the data fetching done asynchronously?
the code you are providing should work the way you expect. Show() -> Show handlers -> SendSaleEmail(). Unless the fetching is done async in another thread let's say. Then the SendSaleEmail() method is called immediately and the data is not fetched. In that case you would need to implement DataFetched event and execute the SendSAleEmail() in that event's handler

Comment: its done old style, by filling a datatable using an adaptor

Comment: its not done in another thread, in the shown event a datatable is filled and coupled to a bindingsource, which is coupled to a grid

Comment: but that code is in the baseform where FormRitDetail is derived from, could that be an issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the baseform of a winform project the code for connecting to the database is moved from the load event to the show event.

There is your real problem. You depend on an event to get executed to get into a valid object state. That's called temporal coupling. It's what makes you experience the current problem.

A general guideline is to never execute business logic within events. Instead create separate methods for that. Those methods can in turn be executed from the event handlers.

The other problem is that you need to load and show a form just so send a send email? At least I interpret your question as that the form will just open, execute and close. Move that code to a new class which just that responsibility.

So the answer to your question is:

1. Do not depend on UI events ensure that business data is loaded. It can be loaded directly but not yet populated into the form until it's ready.
2. Forms have a UI responsibility. They should not be responsible of business logic. Create separate classes.

**Update**

Regarding the actual problem, I just checked reference source for the `Form` class. The `Show()` method just changes the internal state (using `SetWindowLongPtr` WinApi function). Thus nothing is done until the [message pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) processes that message.

There is no guarantee that it's done before the next method call (i.e. `SendSaleEmail`).

Comment: the fetching is a separate method, called in the shown event so that is not the problem. A seperate class to do the emailing is what I am going for this is indeed how it should have been

Comment: But aside from that, I still wonder why method A is called after method B while in code A is before B.

Comment: I agree with teoretical content of this answer, the answer is formally true, but it does not explain nor answer the fact that the data is not fetched in the moment of calling SendSaleEmail(). If the busines logic is placed in the Shown handler, handler shoud be executed and finished  prior the subsequent calls.

Comment: Is it me or does the show event not exist? There is a show function that simply puts the visible property of a window to true (triggering the property setting which triggers the visibility change event). And there is a shown event (async) that is triggered when the form is first drawn. There is (far as I know) no event that triggers on the actual show call unless you programmed one yourself

Comment: but calling show() does makes the form appear and executes the shown() event, but not exactly on the time the show() is called than ? Is there a better method to show a form instead of show() ?

Comment: When you call show() it sets the visible property of a form to true. This triggers the OnVisibleChange event (this event can also be triggered from minimizing the screen though so don't use it in your case). the Shown event is called a tiny bit later, when your computer is done loading and displaying the screen. So there **is** time between show() and then shown event.

Comment: OK that answers my question, not what I had hoped for but i know what to do now. Its not always easy when switching from Delphi to dotnet